# How can I define a custom object (table) in in indexed database?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, indexeddb, indexed-properties

I want to define a custom structure in my indexed database. How can I define a document structure in an indexed database?

Let’s say:

I have one people class

```
export class People {
    id : number
    name: string
    lists: LookUp[]

    constructor() { }
}
```

And the LookUp class is:

```
export class LookUp {
    id: number
    name: string

    constructor() { }
}
```

As a simple structure I define it the below way:

```
const dbConfig: DBConfig = {
    name: 'MyDb',
    version: 1,
    objectStoresMeta: [{
        store: 'people',
        storeConfig: { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true },
        storeSchema: [
            { name: 'name', keypath: 'name', options: { unique: false } }
        ]
    }]
};
```

Now I am stuck with the list define (`lists: LookUp[]`). How can I define the list?

Comment: depends on how you want to query it, you might want a multi-entry index on lists so that you can query for people with a certain value in lists

Comment: @Josh i just to store all data and retrive all data at one time but i am stuck on how to define structure. If you know how to define then plz tell me.

Comment: You misspelled "constructor". Has that any bearing?

Answer (score 0):

I got the clue to solve it.

Define it this way:

```
const dbConfig: DBConfig = {
    name: 'MyDb',
    version: 1,
    objectStoresMeta: [{
        store: 'people',
        storeConfig: { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true },
        storeSchema: [
            { name: 'name', keypath: 'name', options: { unique: false } },
            { name: 'lists', keypath: 'lists', options: { unique: false } }
        ]
    }]
};
```

And add data like this way:

```
 this.dbService
      .bulkAdd('people', [
        {
          name: 'ABC',
          lists: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'Harshad'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Nayan'
          }

          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'DEF',
          lists: [{
            id: 3,
            name: 'Gaurang'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Dharmik'
          }

          ]
        }
      ])
      .subscribe((result) => {
        console.log('result: ', result);
      });
```

It will solve my issue.